# What Is The OnPaint Method In UWP Apps

Tags: c#, winforms, xaml, uwp

I'm working on a UWP app, and I'm creating my own UI components. Until now, I've been working with WinForms, and there's the `OnPaint` method, which I could use to override how a custom component would be drawn. Now that I'm working with UWP, I was wondering if there is a similar method that I could use to draw custom components.

One of my `OnPaint` methods used to look like this:

```cs
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    int buttonHeight = Height;
    int buttonWidth = Width;

    int imgHeight = Height;
    int imgWidth = Height;
    int textPadding = (Height - FontHeight) / 2;
    int textStartX = imgWidth + textPadding;
    int textStartY = textPadding - 3; // Have to get rid of 3, otherwise it's off center


    Graphics g = e.Graphics;

    FillRoundedRectangle(g, new SolidBrush(ButtonColor()), new Rectangle(0, 0, Width, Height), 10); // Background

    if (ImageOnly == Mode.True)
    {
        g.DrawImage(Image, new Rectangle((buttonWidth / 2) - (imgWidth / 2), (buttonHeight / 2) - (imgHeight / 2), imgWidth, imgHeight));
    }
    else
    {
        g.DrawImage(Image, new Rectangle(0, 0, imgWidth, imgHeight));
        g.DrawString(Text, ButtonFont, new SolidBrush(Foreground), new Point(textStartX, textStartY));
    }
}
```

Comment: Win2D provides the `CanvasDrawingSession` class

Comment: Could you please tell us what effect you want to achieve? Do you want to modify the style after the control is displayed? or something else?

Comment: @JunjieZhu-MSFT I added my code from when I was working with WinForms as an example. I'm mostly trying to just be able to draw my own controls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UWP doesn't have a method like `OnPaint`, but you can try using [Win2D CanvasDraw](https://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/WinUI2/html/M_Microsoft_Graphics_Canvas_CanvasDrawingSession_DrawImage_2.htm) in UWP [User Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.usercontrol?view=winrt-22621).

**Right-click** your project-> Select **Add** -> **New Item** -> Choose **User Control**

###### MyUserControl1.xaml

```
<Grid>
    <canvas:CanvasControl Draw="CanvasControl_Draw" ClearColor="CornflowerBlue"/>
</Grid>
```

---

###### MyUserControl1.xaml.cs

```
public sealed partial class MyUserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public MyUserControl1()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

    }

    void CanvasControl_Draw(CanvasControl sender, CanvasDrawEventArgs args)
    {
        args.DrawingSession.DrawEllipse(155, 115, 80, 30, Colors.Black, 3);
        args.DrawingSession.DrawText("Hello, world!", 100, 100, Colors.Yellow);
    }
}
```

###### MainPage.xaml

```
<Grid>
   <local:MyUserControl1/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I didn't know that components had their own XAML code and that's why I couldn't get Win2D to work, so thanks for explaining it! :)